# Slicing starting from a particular item given a specific order

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to implement a cursor-based pagination on Django. I learned a basic knowledge through https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/

I know I need a cursor which points where I am. Before and after. (If I know 'count', I will be able to decide before or after by calculating before + count = after) But I have no idea how to get them by using Django. What I want to do should be like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')[after:after+count]
```

But I do not know how to get the after index of a particular item, which is a cursor in this case. I can only think of it in a Python level.

```
post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')
after = list(queryset).index(post)
result = queryset[after:after+count]
```

In this way, I have to query all the objects from the whole model. I do not think it is ideal, but I do not know either how to execute a query to get the index from a particular item or slice from a particular item.

I only know of a post's slug. My client does not have a primary key. The dataset is never ordered by slugs, but slug is a unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all posts with a `created_date` earlier than the one for a particular `slug` like this:

```
starting_date = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).values('created_date')
later_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=Subquery(starting_date[:1]))\
                          .order_by('-created_date')
```

Now you can slice the last query to only fetch `count` items:

```
later_posts[:count]
```

The latter is still a QuerySet, so the actual query to the database won't involve fetching all items. Just make sure you index your table on `created_date` and `slug` to make it efficient.

If you're getting the value of `slug` from the previous page (the last post of the page), then you'll want to remove it from the new page:

```
later_posts.exclude(slug=slug)[:count]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!! This is certainly better than what I initially thought. But the filter would be mostly created_date__lte, considering people usually scroll down rather than scrolling up to refresh. Then the size of the queryset would be substantial  It also assumes that created_date field is always unique... Is it the best solution? I do know it is better than what I wrote above...

Comment: no, there's no assumption that `created_date` is unique, the only assumption is that `slug` is unique since I take the first entry with the slug. And when you slice the queryset `later_posts`, e.g. `later_posts[:20]`, you create a new queryset, so you're never fetching the entire set of entries.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fetch posts preceding the specific one. Your "after" naming confused me.

Comment: So do you mean that when 'code' later_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=Subquery(starting_date[:1]))\
                          .order_by('-created_date')
is executed, it does not fetch the entire set of created_date__lte=Subquery(starting_date[:1])) ?? But it starts to actually fetch the data when later_posts[:20] was done?  I am confused.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). No, even when `qs = later_posts[:20]` is executed, nothing is evaluated in the db. Only when you actually loop through the items to render them will the queryset be actually evaluated. Querysets are lazy.

Comment: What if there are many 'created_date's and the list shows duplicated posts when refetching? Although I use milliseconds timestamps...

Comment: That's tricky. You don't know if an entry with the exact same timestamp was already shown or not. You probably should deduplicate on the front-end (note that the entry with slug=slug is duplicate already, but can be easily excluded from the above queryset).

Comment: Oh now I get it!!! Is that the reason why you used Post.objects.filter(slug=slug) instead of Post.objects.get(slug=slug)? Because I thought I could do it by post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
queryset = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=post.created_date).order_by('-created_date')

Comment: no, I need the `.values('created_date')` which can only be done on a Queryset. `get()` doesn't return a Queryset but a Post.

Comment: No, the slug field is unique. I see. I will have to think about how to avoid the duplicated timestamp case.

Comment: Why do we need values('created_date') when we can directly access to it by post.created_date? because slug is unique and the post we can get is only one.

Comment: Well, it could be done by fetching the actual post first, but that means 2 queries (one for the specific slug post, the other one for the list of posts). In my example, there's only one query.

Comment: I got you. Thank you for your great help! And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a few classes that help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links. These classes live in django/core/paginator.py.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/

You should at least have a look at this to see how it works, and if it is not quite what you need whether it can be adapted.

Comment: I just looked into it and it seems like it requires me to query the whole objects as the example shows. contact_list = Contacts.objects.all() I am trying to avoid querying all the objects like that.

Comment: @Beginner no, `contact_list` in the example above is a QuerySet and isn't performed. If you then define a paginator on it and fetch a specific page, the actual query that is performed on the database is the paginated query, not the original one.

Comment: However: "If you’re using a QuerySet with a very large number of items, requesting high page numbers might be slow on some databases, because the resulting LIMIT/OFFSET query needs to count the number of OFFSET records which takes longer as the page number gets higher." So it depends how large your table is.

Comment: Oh I see. I will have to look at it more. The table is going to be very large. I was considering to use big int for a primary key!